# Proof writing - $\lim_{x\to 1}{x^n}=1,n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-writing

I was wondering how to write a formal proof of the following proposition,
$$\lim_{x\to 1}{x^n}=1,n\in \mathbb N$$
I tried using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition but I am unable to solve the inequality
$$\lvert x^n-1\rvert<\epsilon$$
I am looking for a formal proof of the statement, and also could anyone please provide me with references to get better at proof writing and proving techniques?

Also, can we generalise it to be true for all $n\in \mathbb R$?

Thanks for any answers!!

Answer (score 1):

From geometric series we have that

$$x^n-1 = (x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})$$

For the moment, consider $x\in(0,2)$. Then we have that

$$|x^n-1| = |x-1|(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}) < |x-1|\cdot(n\cdot2^{n-1})$$

which we want to be less than $\epsilon$. So let

$$\delta = \min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{n\cdot 2^{n-1}}\right)$$

and that completes the proof.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the proof is complete?

Comment: @binarybitarray write up the formal epsilon-delta proof with this choice of delta. What happens? If it is successful, the wording of epsilon-delta says that if for every epsilon there exists a delta. If this delta works then it certainly exists. The whole point of epsilon-delta is to find delta!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the definition of continuity of $x^n$ at x=1. A bit more explicit, since $x^n$ is continuous in $x=1$ you have the following:
\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t. } |1-x|< \delta \implies |x^n - 1^n| = |x^n-1| < \epsilon
\end{equation}